# Error undefined variable $data when Creating Detail by ID

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-10

I want to display the detail page based on the table id that is already available. However, the Undefined variable $data error appears when I enter the code like this.

**Controller**

```
public function show($id)
{
    return view('daftar_mahasiswa', [
        'data' => Mahasiswa::findOrFail($id),
    ]);
}
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('/daftar_mahasiswa/{id}', [MahasiswaController::class, 'show']);
```

**daftar_mahasiswa.blade.php**

```
<button class="action" style="background: #3C91E6">
      <a href="daftar_mahasiswa/{{ $data->id }}" style="color: inherit">
          <i class='bx bxs-detail'></i>
          Detail
      </a>
</button>
```

I hope the code can display the details of the selected data based on the ID.

Comment: You are calling detail action into detail page? It must be listing page first then you are going in detail page, post your listing page code here actual error is there

Comment: so, what should I do then?

Comment: from where you want to redirect to detail page? show that code

Answer (score 0):

The $data variable is not defined here.

You can modify your Controller code like this:

Controller:

```
    public function show($id)
    {
      $data = Mahasiswa::findOrFail($id);
      return view('daftar_mahasiswa', compact('data'));
    }
```

daftar_mahasiswa.blade.php

```
<button class="action" style="background: #3C91E6">
<a href="{{ url('daftar_mahasiswa', $data->id) }}" style="color: 
inherit">
    <i class='bx bxs-detail'></i>
    Detail
</a>
</button>
```

Comment: but i still get the undefined variable $data error

Comment: The what OP has done for passing data is also correct way, S'he is not just actioning detail page from right place

Comment: change the href attribute to {{ url('daftar_mahasiswa', $data->id) }}. then check

Comment: @ArchanaUB it was not working

Comment: did you check if the $data gets the data or not?

Comment: if what you mean is like in this screenshot, I've already done it https://prnt.sc/bWTR0BZN3uVO

Comment: I asked about the data stored in $data variable as a result of Mahasiswa::findOrFail($id). If it does contain result or not

Comment: also include an if check in view page for $data and display something if $data does not contain any value.